# Anything like "Stay on Top" in Web Programming?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Well,

I'm facing a new problem atm.

I have two elements fixed to the top and bottom of the page.And the elements in between them is overlapping the top element.

I did keep both of them fixed.But still this seems to be happening so i was wondering if anything like "Stay on Top" attribute is there in CSS ? or in A language..

http://www.searchr.us/web-search.phtml?search=Test

Here is a pic

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4W4p.gif

As you can see my frames are going over my header.

If it helps : http://www.searchr.us/css/style.css

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look into z-index for your css

```
#header {
    background : url(http://www.searchr.us/images/header.png);
    background-repeat : repeat-x;
    height : 44px;
    min-width : 890px;
    position : fixed;
    top : 0;
    left : 0;
    width : 100%;
    z-index : 1000; /*<---makes sure it's over EVERYTHING*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Add a z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/understanding_css_z-index) that's higher, for example:

```
#header { z-index: 10; }
```